# No logro pasar información de .php a .js usando json

Tags: php, json

Estoy usando `json` para enviar un array hacia un js y recorrerlo, pero cuando lo hago me envía la información contaminada. este es mi código php:

```
function get_main()
    {
        $resultado = null;
        foreach ($this->obtener_datos() as $item => $valor) {
            if ($valor != 0) {
                $resultado[$item] = $valor;
            }
        }
        echo (json_encode($resultado,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
```

cuando imprimo en consola esto es lo que me muestra: un arreglo que cientos de caracteres iniciales que no existen, y por lo tanto no puedo trabajar esa información:

> ���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������{
>       "A": 5,
>       "B": 250,
>       "C": 255,
>       "F": 2675,
>       "Z": 250 }

En mi js tengo lo siguiente, cuando trato de parsear el result para por lo menos ver si puedo ver algo en consola, por supuesto me un error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

```js
$.get(baseUrl + "dashboard/get_main",
            function (result){
                console.log(result);
                var data = JSON.parse(result);
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    console.log(data[i]);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77559/discussion-on-question-by-yasiel-espinosa-no-logro-pasar-informacion-de-php-a).

Answer (score 0):

`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` según su [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php#constant.json-pretty-print). "Utiliza espacios en blanco para formatear los datos devueltos." Es decir, la constante que estas agregando adicional es el que te está "contaminando la información".

Prueba tu código simplemente sin esa constante.

```
function get_main()
    {
        $resultado = null;
        foreach ($this->obtener_datos() as $item => $valor) {
            if ($valor != 0) {
                $resultado[$item] = $valor;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($resultado);
    }
```

Solo tienes que llamar a la función de la siguiente manera para evitar espacios vacíos.

```
ob_start();  //-- Activa el almacenamiento en búfer de la salida
get_main();  //-- Aquí llamas a tu función
$html = ob_get_contents(); //-- Obtienes toda la salida de la funcion
ob_end_clean();
echo $html; //-- Imprimes el resultado
```

Comment: es verdad lo que planteas, pero usé JSON_PRETTY_PRINT para poder visualizarlo mejor en consola, es innesesacio como planteas

Comment: @Ing.Yasiel He editado la respuesta para que quede un poco mas claro. Por tu comentario el problema no yace en la función, sino en como/cuando muestres los datos.